# Generate .apk file from bitbucket pipeline in react native project

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I am trying to generate a .apk file everytime i make a merge to the development branch in my react native project.

```
pipelines:
branches:
    development: # Replace with the name of your specific branch
      - step:
          name: Build and package APK
          image: node:16.0.0
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk # Install OpenJDK 11
            - wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-7302050_latest.zip -O android-sdk-tools.zip # Download Android SDK tools
            - mkdir -p android-sdk/cmdline-tools
            - unzip -q android-sdk-tools.zip -d android-sdk/cmdline-tools # Unzip Android SDK tools
            - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk
            - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
            - yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses # Accept Android SDK licenses
            - $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.3" "platforms;android-30" # Install required Android packages
            - npm install # Install project dependencies
            - npx react-native run-android --variant=release # Build and package the APK
            - cp android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk $BITBUCKET_PIPELINES_ARTIFACTS/apk # Copy the APK to artifacts
```

the pipeline always fail with this error

```
+ yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
bash: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager: No such file or directory
```

---

```
my ANDROID_HOME is $PWD/android-sdk and BITBUCKET_PIPELINES_ARTIFACTS is /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/artifacts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `chmod 777 ./` before the line that failed.

Here we have configured our automation to run in pipeline and had the same error. We are using an custom docker image but maybe it solves your problem.